# Invoke java method through perl and get the return value without using inbuilt functions

Tags: java, perl

I have a Java program which has a static method

```
     private static int checkURL(String currentURL)
```

From my perl script, I want to call this method and get return value of this method.

I have a constraint that I can't use any inbuilt Perl modules offered by CPAN.

I am thinking to call Java through system() command in Perl but issue is how to call this method and get the return code?

Comment: If it's a private method, how would you even call it in Java?

Answer (score 0):

call external command and get back result (straight from http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands)

```
#-- scalar context
$result = `command arg1 arg2`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Java`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Java/) module

```
use Java;
my $java = new Java;
my $obj = $java->create_object("com.my.Class","constructor parameter");
$obj->checkURL("http://www.google.com/");
$obj->setId(5);
```

[Iniline::Java](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline%3a%3aJava) is also a famous module for Java/Perl integration.

Edit: I have a constraint that I can't use any inbuilt perl modules offered by CPAN.

Oh sorry I didn't see that. I had tried something like below some time ago.

---

Hello.java

```
class Hello {
  // Your program begins with a call to main().
  public static void main(String args[]) {
  System.out.println("This is a simple Java program to test return code.\n");
  System.exit(100);
  }
}
```

test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings; 
my $command = "java Hello";
print "Command is $command:\n";
system($command);
my $retval = $? >> 8;
print "The return code is $?\n";
print "retval is $retval\n";
```

Run it

> perl test.pl

Output

```
Command is java Hello:
This is a simple Java program to test return code.

The return code is 25600
retval is 100
```